# Use properties of the integral and calculate, without extensive accounts:

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-5}^5 x^2-x^{10}\sin(x)+x^5\sqrt{1+x^4}$$

Which properties can i use to solve this quickly?

Comment: Additivity, in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: the integral of an odd function on an interval symmetric about the origin, is $0$. Or symbolically, if $f$ is odd ($f(-x)=-f(x)$), you have:
$$\color{blue}{\int_{-a}^a f(x) \,\mbox{d}x = 0}$$
Combine this with the linearity of the integral:
$$\int_{-5}^5 x^2-x^{10}\sin(x)+x^5\sqrt{1+x^4} \,\mbox{d}x \\= 
\int_{-5}^5 x^2 \,\mbox{d}x
-
\color{blue}{\int_{-5}^5 x^{10}\sin(x) \,\mbox{d}x}
+
\color{blue}{\int_{-5}^5 x^5\sqrt{1+x^4} \,\mbox{d}x}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is an odd function then $\int_{-a}^af(x)\,dx=?$

Answer (score 2):

Split interval using additivity. 
The first is even, the other two are odds.
Second and third integrals are equal to $0$ as other answers have already said, the first is obvious.